# Vscode how to disable type annotation in pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I recently switched to vscode for python but I'm having a bit of trouble with overzealous completions in pylance.

Specially with function overrides, pylance seems to just automatically infer the types and inject annotations everywhere. I'd like to disable the annotations completion without disabling the entire autocompletion.

is it possible?

For example, when I create new class.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __ini
```

this is what autocompletion does:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
```

it's very annoying to have to delete text added by an autocomplete
I only want this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a bug in the product, but a proposal to fix the behavior exists in the form of a GitHub discussion. You can see that discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/2593

Answer (score -1):

In pylance extention settings you can turn it off.

[image]

Comment: That's not what that setting does. It controls the tooltip-like return types that are injected into your code as you type, not what's included in autocompletion. Inlay hints aren't actually part of the document, it's only visible while you have the document open in the editor.